# How to fully customize nopCommerce 3.50 theme according to requirement?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, nopcommerce

I am trying to make a eCommerce site using nopCommerce 3.5 and new in it, I've a demo site and have make totally same as the site. I know basic of C#, asp.net, HTML, CSS but i can not properly able to modify the theme. I've follow all the documentation for designer at nopCommerce site but that is not giving a proper concept. I want to
1.Adding custom links to Menu Bar items.
2.Adding different style like demo site in categories bar.
3.Allowing comparing products.
And so on
The demo site is [Demo Site](http://drinstech.com/baatighar/)

I have searched a lot but not getting proper guidenc. If.If anyone can provide me any kind of tutorial regarding this it'll be very helpful.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see you mention anything about **MVC**.
You should look up **MVC** (in general) and **ASP.NET MVC version 3+** (in specific) so you can understand how the NopCommerce web project (*Presentation\Nop.Web*) is organized.

Make sure you know what **Controllers, Controller Actions, Models, Views and Partial Views** are. Then, you will be able to find them inside that project. Also see how **URL routing** works in MVC, so that you can determine the Controller and Action/View of a webpage so you can go to the right files to make your changes. Example: www.example.com/Controller/Action (where the Action has a name similar to the View it loads)

Also, make sure that you understand the **Razor** syntax used in ASP.NET MVC views in NopCommerce.

Then, for theme customization, you mainly need to work in the Themes folder (for CSS and images) and Views folder (for HTML, roughly speaking).
These folders are both in the Nop.Web project located inside the solution at: Presentation\Nop.Web.

Sorry that I can't recommend you a specific tutorial. But searching about the things I highlighted should give you plenty resources to get started.